# ¿Cómo respaldar archivos y ver las versiones anteriores que ha tenido en visual studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, control-de-versiones

Actualmente trabajo con el Visual Studio Profesional 2013, con lenguaje C# y me gustaría hacer respaldos de mis archivos que he creado. Antes tuve la oportunidad de trabajar en equipo, donde varios de mis colegas subían los archivos a un repositorio. Uno tenía la opción de bloquear los archivos que uno no trabaja por seguridad, además, si uno trabaja en un archivo especifico, el otro colega no le podía modificar el archivo, al menos que uno lo libere. Además, uno podía ver las versiones anteriores que tenía desarrollado y comparar.

¿Alguien sabe como podría utilizar esta funcionalidad? Recuerdo que había una opción en Team Explorer que se conectaba a un servidor para dejar respaldos, pero de ahí, nada más.

Comment: por la experiencia que ya has trabajado con un repositorio considera `Visual Studio Team Services` (anteriormente Visual Studio Online) que tiene las características que indicas en tu pregunta, como indica la respuesta de @Miguel. Tiene una versión gratuita donde para registrarse no necesitas tarjeta de crédito, la única limitante es la cantidad de usuarios (5 usuarios).

Comment: @Danielo, en tu pregunta ¿Quieres saber como funciona dicho versionamiento del que preguntas o que Utilidad podrías utilizar para versionar tu código fuente?, porque das a entender que quieres saber como funciona, si estás mal edita tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu pregunta está tu respuesta, necesitas un repositorio para tu código. 
Hay muchos tipos como Git, SVN, TFS, etc. Algunos son totalmente gratis y otros de pago o de pago en versiones profesionales. Yo personalmente soy partidario de TFS(Team foundation Server) por la integración propia dentro de visual studio que ya tiene. Te recomiendo que te crees una cuenta en https://www.visualstudio.com/vso/ para poder probarlo.
Un saludo!

Edito:
En un principio con la cuenta de visual studio online gratuita, podría usarla para crear su repositorio tfs y poder Subir/descargar el código

Answer (score 0):

Estimado,

Yo me inclinaría mas por GIT y GITHUB. Aunque la curva de aprendizaje en un poco lenta es muy recomendable. Ademas de ser 100% gratis